# Where and how is the authentication cookie stored with the new authentication system?

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, authentication

My browser is configured with several cookie restrictions (clear cookies on exit, no third party cookies, and privacy badger on top of that). I found that after SE recently switched to a new authentication architecture my credentials are not saved between one navigation session and another, despite the addresses of the SE sites I regularly visit being whitelisted.

So,  **in which cookies does the new authentication architecture store credentials?** What sites do I have to whitelist to be able to stay logged in?

Comment: I don't think they ever used cookies, it always was local storage.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see that stack exchange does store two local storage keys (nuCounter and se:fkey), but they are correctly preserved across sessions, so that does not seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on some experiments and code I have to log me in without using a browser seem to prove that the only cookie you need per site is the `acct` cookie from the domain `.stackexchange.com`:

[image: acct cookie in Dev Console]

Removing that cookie logs you out immediately and the toolbar switch to the anonymous state when you refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks! I still have to understand which extension is responsible, but it seems like the auth cookie for stackexchange.com gets saved only when I start Firefox in safe mode. :/ Anyway everything is fixed now.