# Why does Stack Overflow (and possibly other stacks) have cookies which expire in 2055?

Tags: discussion, cookies

[image: Two cookies from the Meta Stack and Stack Overflow which will expire in 2055]

Personally, I just want to know for what purpose they're used for.

Comment: I believe they are used to keep you logged in if you're a registered user and the cookies serve as a mean to keep track of the users that choose to remain unregistered. You can have a cookie only account aka, be an unregistered user.

Comment: Yeah, see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281134/how-long-does-an-unregistered-users-cookie-remain-valid/281138#281138 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263360/where-and-how-is-the-authentication-cookie-stored-with-the-new-authentication-sy/263363#263363

Comment: Yeah, needs a dev to explain. I wonder if Adam Lear has a few minutes left to elaborate on that

Comment: Those cookies have preservatives and hence longer shelf life. :)

Comment: That's the date when Atwood will return. All questions with upvoted answers will be archived to a higher database, and the final battle with Quora and Yahoo will begin.

Comment: Preservatives.​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍

Comment: Damnit, too slow :(

Answer (score 3):

I would ask: why would they choose to have your cookies automatically expire at any point?

Stack can clear the cookies when it's appropriate for them, such as when you log out.

Your browser can clear the cookies when it's appropriate for you, based on your privacy settings, storage requirements, or whatever else you consider important.

Newer APIs, like Storage and IndexedDB, do not require (or even support) auto-expiration dates, beyond the high-level choice of "indefinitely" versus "session". Only cookies require this. Choosing an arbitrary date in the far future is a good way to ignore the requirement.

Comment: you answered the title, can you elaborate on what is asked in the body: *I just want to know for what purpose they're used for.*? (assuming you feel that is appropriate)